# Delete duplicates in mysql (two parameters)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to delete duplicates from a table which contains cities, there may however be multiple cities with the same name across different countries, example from table:

`+------+----------+---------------------+
| locId | country   | city               |
+------+----------+---------------------+
|    1 | DE       | Hamburg             |
|    2 | US       | Hamburg             |
|    3 | DE       | Hamburg             |
|    4 | DE       | Hamburg             |
|    5 | US       | Hamburg             |
+------+----------+---------------------+`

Now 1,3,4 are the same (different zip codes, but that doesn't matter, safe to remove) and 2,5 are the same. What query could be run to leave only 1 and 2 in the table and deleting the other duplicates ?

Comment: **`DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id IN (3,4,5)`** ?

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE id FROM table t1, table t2 WHERE t1.country <> t2.country AND t1.city = t2.city
```